# using if.. statement to check if user exists in table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a login on a local server that checks if a user exists in a table before adding any data.

This is the code I used to select the user information:

```
$name1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentname']);
$num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentnum']);
$qw = "SELECT name FROM students WHERE name = '$name1'";
$qw1 = "SELECT studentnum FROM students WHERE studentnum = '$num'";
$namematch = mysql_query($qw) or die(mysql_error());
$nummatch = mysql_query($qw1) or die(mysql_error());
```

But, I am stumped as to what I should enter for my if() statement to register as TRUE if data is retrieved from each query:

```
if (!($namematch && $nummatch) {
    die('Name or student number do not match those on record');
}
```

The above code does not equal true, even when I am entering incorrect information.

Comment: You have to count the rows selected, what you're doing is checking if the queries were successful.

Comment: There will be many standard logics for login in PHP pages, google it.. I'm sure you'll find the answer

Comment: Print it out.  What do you see?  What about print_r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
    if (!($namematch && $nummatch) {
        die('Name or student number do not match those on record');
    }
```

the $namematch and $nummatch is always be true

$namematch and $nummatch just mysql_query resource identify ,resource type always exists

perhaps  u should do this:

```
    $nameExists = mysql_fetch_assoc($namematch);
    $numExists = mysql_fetch_assoc($nummatch);
    if (!($nameExists && $numExists )) {
        die('Name or student number do not match those on record');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have executed the query, but have not fetched the data. This:

```
mysql_fetch_array($namematch)[0]
```

Will get you the data.

Please be aware that mysql_* functions are deprecated and insecure. You should use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$namematch = mysql_num_rows($namematch);
$nummatch = mysql_num_rows($nummatch);
if (!($namematch && $nummatch) {
    die('Name or student number do not match those on record');
}
```

PLEASE USE PDO FROM NOW ON!